# 'USB Drive' Access is denied

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I put a USB drive in the port and tried to read it but an error message pops up.

```
E:/ is not accessible.
Access is denied.
```

It was a public computer so I don't have access to Control Panel or something like that. What's wrong?

Comment: There are two possible explainations.  The first USB devices are disabled on the computer in question.  The second possible explaination is the device no longer is functioning.

Comment: Group Policy may be in effect. There may also be a possibility that the USB drive is formatted with NTFS and the ACLs do not grant the `All Users` group read access.

Comment: I would suggest plugging the memory stick into another computer to see if it functions there.  Also you can plug a different memory stick into the public computer and see if that one works.  What OS is the public computer? If you get a new memory stick plug it into the public computer and it works then your memory stick could be broken.  If the brand new memory stick does not work then it is some thing to do with the public computer.  The port could be partially broken, it could be disabled by network policy, it could be disabled in the BIOS. More research is needed.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to run [CHKDSK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872425.aspx) ?

I had this "Inaccessible Drive" error, where the USB Flash drive was recognized by Windows, but its file-system was inaccessible: 
[image]

At first I tried all kind of data recovery tools, but it was just worthless...
While *chkdsk* fixed it right away:

Open CMD as Administrator and (assuming your flash drive is H:) run:

```
chkdsk H: /R
```

Once completed (in my case there were no prints in console after a while) - disconnect and reconnect your USB flash drive.

Comment: You can't run chkdsk on an inaccessible drive. And duplicate answers on very different questions, saying you had the same error seems... strange.

Comment: Mr. @Journeyman "Geek", you're misleading the readers. In case you think an "inaccessible drive" cannot be fixed with chkdsk - you wrong! Please verify yourself next time.

Comment: The asker probably didn't have permissions to run CHKDSK on the computer.  Also, because it was so long ago, apparently @user67275 never bothered to update the question or post their own answer.