# How to recover possibly broken usb stick

Tags: usb, windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I was using my usb stick, and suddenly it just disappeared from my computer. I went into the Windows disk manager, and it's still visible there, when i try to change the drive letter it says: "file not found". I need help.

Comment: It sounds like the drive no longer is fully functional.  Have you tried another machine to verify that is the case?

Comment: You can check this superuser entry, the answer contains some steps you could check too (like uninstalling the device from device manager and scan for hardware changes): http://superuser.com/questions/463861/usb-stick-doesnt-mount-but-is-detected-how-to-repair

Comment: So you tried the device on another machine, and it doesn't work, or it did work?

Comment: it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can try something hardware-related:

- Clean the pins of the USB-stick with alcohol and let it dry.
- Try to cool the USB-stick to +6 deg celsius (use normal fridge, avoid humidity).
- Try to heat the USB-stick to a kind of working temperature (but not too much heat of course).
- Try to use a USB-cable and/or external hub (that means little different electricity values for the stick).

At least try different computers with different OS´s.

At the very least, you can try to repair or let repair the stick at a data rescue center.

Concerning the future, a card reader with SD-chip might be a more reliable solution (the data chip can be removed), than a USB-stick with a solded chip. Certainly that doesn´t help you now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the USB stick has disappeared because the partition table on the stick has become corrupted. You need to use some partition recovery tool. There are many free tools available for this purpose. Try easeus or Lazesoft.